# Use an API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am building a react native app where I need to have a payment method and upon checking [their APIs](https://perfectmoney.com/sample-api.html) I see that they don't have Javascript so I am trying to use their API.

Here's their PHP way of getting an [Account balance](https://perfectmoney.com/acct/samples/parse_balance.txt) .

Upon trying using axios to do the same

```
 const handlePaymentConfirmation = async () => {
    const apiUrl = "https://perfectmoney.com/acct/balance.asp";
    const requestData = {
      AccountID: "1234",
      PassPhrase: "somePassphrase",
    };
    try {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl, requestData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Response:", response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("API Error:", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating user paid status", error);
    }
  };
```

I got the following response :

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Balance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Balance</h1>
  Error: No values passed to API
  <input name='ERROR' type='hidden' value='No values passed to API'>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How can I use that API when I'm using Javascript ?

Comment: Have you tried `https://perfectmoney.com/acct/balance.asp?AccountID=10000&PassPhrase=111111` as url?

Comment: Yes I just gave that a try and it worked. Got a different error so I guess that makes me delete this question

Comment: I don't use Axios, but looking at https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config I _think_ you've misunderstood how to pass the parameters into your .get() call

Comment: Try `const requestData = { params: {
      AccountID: "1234",
      PassPhrase: "somePassphrase",
    } }` . The parameters are just one property within the overall request config.

Comment: In fact the second example at https://axios-http.com/docs/example shows exactly that.

Comment: @ADyson yes you're right that solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had omitted the **params** option in the requestData, Here's how it should be done

```
  const handlePaymentConfirmation = async () => {
    const apiUrl = "https://perfectmoney.com/acct/balance.asp";
    const requestData = {
      AccountID: "1234",
      PassPhrase: "somePassphrase",
    };
    try {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl, requestData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Response:", response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("API Error:", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating user paid status", error);
    }
  };
```